# Which graphic drivers should I Install and how?

Tags: drivers, rhel6, intel, graphics

I have a system on which RHEL6 is installed.
I need to install proper graphic drivers.
I checked my graphic card simply by this command

```
#lspci -v | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0162 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

When I searched its drivers I found [this](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) (01.org/linuxgraphics/)link.
But I don't know which drivers to choose and how to install them.

I don't think that my drivers are proper, because when I select System->Preferences-> Desktop Effects  I got error message: "The Composite Extension is not available".

Comment: So what did Red Hat say when you called them?

Comment: not yet registered with RHN.

Comment: Go register the system and then call Red Hat.

Answer (score 3):

EL6 already includes Intel graphics drivers. You don't need to do anything unless you have a specialized need that requires you to replace the system graphics drivers. (You don't, or you would have mentioned it already.)

In particular, the i915 driver included with EL 6.3 already includes support for your Ivy Bridge graphics.